# Do we call the outer layer of a longan "shell" or "skin"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Usually, the outer layer of a longan is quite hard and noone eats it. You have to remove that outer layer before eating the flesh inside.

Do we call the outer layer of a longan "**shell**" or "**skin**"?

And also, which verb is used to express "**to remove that outer layer**".

For example, "**you have to shell/peel the longan before eating**".

Comment: Longans are unknown here in the UK, but Wikipedia calls it a shell.

Comment: @KateBunting, if it is called "a shell", then which verb is used when you say you want to remove it, "to shell" or "to peel"?

Comment: How am I supposed to know when I've never seen one? The Wikipedia article refers to the brittleness of the shell making the fruit 'easy to peel'.

Comment: @KateBunting, you can make a trip to Southest Asia, there are a lot of interesting fruit there

Comment: Pretty sure you've asked the same question before..... Anyway .. it's called [deshelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deshell)

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/256412/how-to-express-to-remove-peanuts-skin-with-your-fingers-in-english/256466#256466

Comment: @Wistful, I am looking for a common word that an average mom would use, "deshell" could be too far-out

Comment: @Tom, Then use *peel* or *rub off*.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary, in its definition of  "longan", refers to the "skin". ("The fruit of a South-East Asian evergreen tree, Dimocarpus longan (family Sapindaceae), having a yellowish skin and sweet white flesh. Also: the tree itself.")  The Cambridge dictionary online, however, refers to its "brown shell".